# Can't install Pymatgen [Could not build wheels for pymatgen]

Tags: visual-c++, python-wheel, pymatgen

I'm trying to install pymatgen but it returns the following error:

```
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pymatgen, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

The complete error is as follows:

```
Using cached pymatgen-2021.2.8.1.tar.gz (3.0 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
```

Then it mentions a lot of requirements already satisfied (since I tried to download it before).

```
Building wheels for collected packages: pymatgen
  Building wheel for pymatgen (pyproject.toml) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\python\python.exe' 'c:\python\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py' build_wheel 'C:\Users\koenh\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpd_p81gmj'
       cwd: C:\Users\koenh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-vkbl5ix0\pymatgen_4be9d669cc1445638c612c82c93b02fb
  Complete output (469 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
```

Then it starts copying a rough 200 files and then returns:

```
    building 'pymatgen.optimization.linear_assignment' extension
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pymatgen
Failed to build pymatgen
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pymatgen, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Then i downloaded Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 but still no succes. Then finally I received this error:

```
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\python\python.exe' 'c:\python\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\koenh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-5hyyx30i\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'numpy>=1.20.1' 'setuptools>=43.0.0'
       cwd: None
  Complete output (2 lines):
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy>=1.20.1 (from versions: 1.3.0, 1.4.1, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.6.0, 1.6.1, 1.6.2, 1.7.0, 1.7.1, 1.7.2, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.9.0, 1.9.1, 1.9.2, 1.9.3, 1.10.0.post2, 1.10.1, 1.10.2, 1.10.4, 1.11.0, 1.11.1, 1.11.2, 1.11.3, 1.12.0, 1.12.1, 1.13.0rc1, 1.13.0rc2, 1.13.0, 1.13.1, 1.13.3, 1.14.0rc1, 1.14.0, 1.14.1, 1.14.2, 1.14.3, 1.14.4, 1.14.5, 1.14.6, 1.15.0rc1, 1.15.0rc2, 1.15.0, 1.15.1, 1.15.2, 1.15.3, 1.15.4, 1.16.0rc1, 1.16.0rc2, 1.16.0, 1.16.1, 1.16.2, 1.16.3, 1.16.4, 1.16.5, 1.16.6, 1.17.0rc1, 1.17.0rc2, 1.17.0, 1.17.1, 1.17.2, 1.17.3, 1.17.4, 1.17.5, 1.18.0rc1, 1.18.0, 1.18.1, 1.18.2, 1.18.3, 1.18.4, 1.18.5, 1.19.0rc1, 1.19.0rc2, 1.19.0, 1.19.1, 1.19.2, 1.19.3, 1.19.4, 1.19.5)
  ERROR: No matching distribution found for numpy>=1.20.1
```

Anyone has any idea how I can solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!